# Using SQLite with A PageView

Tags: android, xml, sqlite

I am trying to create an Android App that fetch data from the SQLite database and display them in a PageView( Swipe View). The App crashes anytime I try to run. Please help me to look at my code to see where I am getting it wrong.

My Main Activity is this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    DataBaseAccess databaseAccess = DataBaseAccess.getInstance(this);
    databaseAccess.open();
    List<String> quotes = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
    databaseAccess.close();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),getApplicationContext());


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";
    private static final String Name_Key = "Name_Key";

    /*public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }*/

    /**
     * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
     * number.
     */
   /* public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }*/

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        Bundle bundle=getArguments();

        if (bundle!=null)
        {
            String name=bundle.getString(Name_Key);
            setValues(rootView,name);
        }


        return rootView;
    }
    private void setValues( View v, String name)
    {
        TextView textview=(TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        textview.setText(name);
    }
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    List<String> name;
    String[] name1;
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
        super(fm);
        DataBaseAccess databaseAccess = DataBaseAccess.getInstance(null);
        databaseAccess.open();
        name=databaseAccess.getQuotes();
        for (int i=0; i<=name.size();i++)
        {
           name1[i]=name.get(i);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
        bundle.putString(PlaceholderFragment.Name_Key,name1[position]);

        PlaceholderFragment deviceFragment= new PlaceholderFragment();
        deviceFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
        return deviceFragment;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return name1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return name1[position];
    }
}
}
```

My Class that Access the database and returns a list of Strings

```
public class DataBaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private static SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DataBaseAccess instance;

/**
 * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DataBaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context the Context
 * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
 */
public static DataBaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DataBaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public void open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        //this.database.close();
    }
}

/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a List of quotes
 */
public ArrayList getQuotes() {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM quotes", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        list.add(cursor.getString(0));
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
}
```

My Activity_main file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="org.heywhyconcept.myapplicationscroll.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

My Fragment_main file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="org.heywhyconcept.myapplicationscroll.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/section_label"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="YUSUF AYOMIDE"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="text"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have provided, it seems that you are trying to access the table `quotes` using a `SELECT` statement *without properly defining and creating the database's tables first*.

You need to explicitly define the tables that should be present in your database. There is an excellent example of how to do this in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) which I will paraphrase here:

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "myDatabase.db";
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
    "CREATE TABLE quotes (" +
    "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
    "quote TEXT)";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    //Create tables here
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a ready database in my program that I'm accessing through a class with this code.   ' public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "quotes.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}' . It worked fine when I displayed it on a list view. Please help me out

Comment: @AyomideAdekunle Then please provide the output of any logs you have that show the crash

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                       Process: org.heywhyconcept.myapplicationscroll, PID: 15057
                                                                                       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.heywhyconcept.myapplicationscroll/org.heywhyconcept.myapplicationscroll.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerExceptionat android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2447)

Comment: Please see: [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Thank you very much @Ed George I will look into it. Please do you have any tutorial of step-to-follow to use SQLite with PageView(SwipeView)

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a tutorial site - please use a search engine